# Liquid sealant with MLS gasket on intake manifold?

Tags: gasket, intake-manifold

I recently took the intake manifold off my 2009 Honda Fit.

The mating surfaces of the lower intake manifold, gasket, and cylinder head were uneven, so I cleaned them via acetone and hand sanded with 220 grit sandpaper.

Now I understand that the sandpaper on the aluminum probably wasn't a good idea, and I'm a little concerned about the seal. I'm replacing the gasket with a new one. Should I also apply a liquid sealant? If so, what kind?

I'm pretty sure the manifold and cylinder head are aluminum (please check me), and the gasket MLS.

Note that the below images are from the net, mine was much more corroded.

Thank you!

Exploded view of what I'm referring to:
[image: intake manifold cylinder head]

Cylinder head:
[image]

Gasket:
[image]

Intake:
[image]

Comment: "sandpaper on the aluminum probably wasn't a good idea" not to mention all the grit that fell into the intake ports. I would use a thin layer of Ultra Grey Sealant on both sides of the gasket, assemble and let cure for 24 hours before starting engine.

Comment: @Moab I did blow out the intake ports using compressed air, making sure to stick the nozzle as far in as I could to blow the debris out instead of in. Still, not super smart on my part. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Only issue with that is at least one intake valve is open on on 4 cylinder engines and it can get into the cylinder, you are probably ok, lesson learned, What I do is stuff the ports with paper towels prior to sanding, don't forget to remove them before assembly!